# What's this button/ thumbnail layout called?

Tags: gui-design, mobile, buttons, terminology, thumbnail

What's this button layout called? I've been looking for the appropriate name for this layout so I can learn more about its use case and where it's best to be used but I've been dumbfounded for a while now.

[image]

I'm making something similar to it for a mobile app but only in an empty state, but I wanted to learn more about it before I do implement in the design. so far I've made this, where other than the button to add more, there's only outlines.
[image]

Comment: Hi Ken. I’m not sure whether the patterns are the same here. The one that you made, suggests that you can add recipients which will appear in a horizontal list to the right of the add button. But the pattern you pasted “Choose a project template” is kind of a picker only, as far as I can tell. Meaning your “Blank project” is not going to appear in the list.

Comment: It’s an interesting question, though. I’ve also seen it several times. It’s kind of a template-picker? You can create something based on a template, or from scratch.

Comment: I guess functionally yes, they are quite different, I wanted to take advantage of the horizontal list layout as a kind of picker when its filled out. and I guess maybe that's why I'm having a hard time looking up research on this kind of layout.

Comment: I see. Sorry, I’m more in interaction design where patterns mean something more. Well if you limit it to the layout, it’s simply a grid/card layout, I guess, as Ljubiša Kukulj stated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure for a specific and "correct" naming of this element but I would call it probably a card since I would be desperate to find a better naming for it. You could see if that fits your need.